# Turn json string into an object array in angular cli

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I would like to turn a json string array into an object array.
In this case I have a string receiving from backend

```
[{"id_pk":3,"heroname":"myherooo"},{"id_pk":12,"heroname":"Narco"}]
```

and I would like to turn this string into a Hero array and then return it.

My current code:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
                  let heroes: Hero[];
                  let jo = response.text(); // [{"id_pk":3,"heroname":"myherooo"},{"id_pk":12,"heroname":"Narco"}]
                  console.log("jo: "+jo);
                  for(let i=0;i<jo.length;i++){
                      console.log("ele:  "+JSON.parse(response.text()[i])); // SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
                      heroes[i] = JSON.parse(response.text()[i]);
                  }
                  heroes;

                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

Can anybody help?

**Update:**

This is the solution:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                .map (t=>t.json())
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.map(i => new Hero(i.id_pk, i.heroname)))
                .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map(t=> t.json())`:

```
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .map (t=>t.json())
        .toPromise()
        ...
```

Comment: ok this this turns it into an object array but I need Hero[] to return  `.map (t=>t.json())
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                  response as Hero[]; // object array`
                })

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you were trying to loop and access the array before parsing the JSON in :

```
heroes[i] = JSON.parse(response.text()[i]);
//And then in
heroes[i] = JSON.parse(response.text()[i]);
```

You should parse the JSON before accessing the array an looping over its elements:

```
let jo = JSON.parse(response.text()); 
console.log("jo: "+jo);
for(let i=0;i<jo.length;i++){
     console.log("ele:  "+jo[i]); 
     heroes[i] = jo[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor in your Hero class. Should look something like:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(hero?: any) {
    if (hero) {
      this.id = hero.id;
      this.name = hero.name;
    }
  }
}
```

now you need to map your data. I'll give you an example of how i would do it:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
  response => this.heroes = response.map(h => new Hero(h)),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

Edit:

By the way, i googled your question after i posted this answer and i immediately found a solution [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/). You can look for .map on the page and get more examples.

```
this.results = res.json().results.map(item => { 
  return new SearchItem(
      item.trackName,
      item.artistName,
      item.trackViewUrl,
      item.artworkUrl30,
      item.artistId
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => <Hero[]>res.json());
}
```

Comment: @ninjaxelite i will post my answer check and try this

Comment: sadly the response is undefined cause another component is calling `slice` method on `Hero[]`